# Why is this limit integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

In the book Real Analysis by Bass, it asks to evaluate the Lebesgue integral

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{n} \bigg(1 - \frac{x}{n} \bigg)^{n} \log(2+\cos(x/n)) \ \mathrm{d}x $$

I assume I should use one of the convergence theorems.

Define the integrand as $f_n(x)$.

Is it possible to evaluate this even if $f_n(x)$ is not defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ for some values of $n \in \mathbb{R}$? To be specific, $f_n(x)$ is defined for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and the integral as well, if $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Is this enough for the limit to be integrable? Another thing that confuses me is that the upper limit of the integral is $n$, should I define the sequence of functions $g_n = \int_{0}^{n} \left(1 - \frac{x}{n} \right)^{n} \log(2+\cos(x/n)) \, \mathrm{d}x$ for each positive integer $n$?

My edit:

What I mean is that the integrand is real-valued on $(0,n)$ but I don't know how to tackle cases where the integration interval varies with the limit.

Comment: What do you mean when you are saying both '... $f_n(x)$ is not defined for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$' and 'To be specific, $f_n(x)$ is defined for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$' simultaneously? Also, is your $g_n$ really a function, rather than a number?

Comment: I suspect that you are baffled because the domain of integration varies in $n$. The standard trick to circumvent this issue is to extend the integrand by setting zero outside the domain of integration. In this case, you will be considering $$f_n(x) = \left(1 - \frac{x}{n}\right)^n \log(2+\cos(x/n)) \mathbf{1}_{[0,n]}(x), $$ where $\mathbf{1}_{[0,n]}(x)$ is the indicator function which is $1$ (resp. $0$) if $x \in [0,n]$ (resp. $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus[0,n]$). Then your integral is simply $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ and you should have no problem applying convergence theorems.

Comment: I mean that $f_n(x)$ is not necessarily real-valued for all $x$ if $n$ is not a positive integer. Can I build my sequence only out of the functions $f_n$ where $n$ is a positive integer? Also, yes. I am confused by the domain of integration. Won't this cause problems if the resulting functions are not continuous?

Comment: Since the limit of a sequence depends only the terms with sufficiently large indices, people often do not care about explicating the starting index of the sequence inside the limit. That being said, you can safely restrict your attention to the case $n \geq 1$.

Comment: Let's say that I have a function $f_n(x)$ that is real-valued only for $n \notin \mathbb{Z}$. Can I use, for example the sequence $f_{1/2}, f_{3/2}, f_{5/2}, ...$?

Comment: I don't get it. The limit only concerns the values of $f_n$ for large integers $n$, so why do you even bother with $f_{\bullet}$ at half-integers? And most of all, how is your question related to OP? The function $$ f_n(x) = \left(1 - \frac{x}{n}\right)^n \log(2+\cos(x/n)) \mathbf{1}_{[0,n]}(x) $$ is well-defined for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and for any $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$.

Comment: I made up a different specific case. This is related to the previous comment you made. I want to know if I can build the sequence of functions $f_n$ however I want as long as $n$ is increasing (e.g. not made up of integer values). I know it is well-defined for the case you mention. This is a separate hypothetical case I thought of with your comment.

Comment: First, continuity is never an issue for Lebesgue integral. To lower down your worry on this matter, let me mention that the following claim holds: $$\int_{E}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\tilde{f}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$holds for any measurable set $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, integrable function $f:E\to\mathbb{R}$, and its extension$$\tilde{f}(x)=\begin{cases}f(x),&x\in E\\0,&x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus E\end{cases}$$ The use of indicator function in our case is simply a trick for shortening this piecewise notation. (This can be found in any sensible textbook on measure theory.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99459/discussion-between-the-bosco-and-sangchul-lee).

Answer (score 5):

$0 \leq I_{(0,n)}(x) (1-\frac  xn)^{n} \log(2+cos (\frac x n))\leq (\log 3)e^{-x}$ and $e^{-x}$ is integrable on $(0,\infty)$. So we can apply DCT.

Answer (score 3):

$HINT$

$1_{[0,n]}\leq 1, \forall n \in \Bbb{N}$

Note that $|\log{(2+\cos{(x/n)})}| \leq \log{3}$

Also since $1-x \leq e^{-x}$ we have that $$(1-\frac{x}{n})^ \leq e^{-\frac{x}{n}}$$

So by m DCT you have the limit.

Comment: Is there a problem with multiplying the integrand by the indicator function if the resulting function is not continuous everywhere?

Comment: No is not a problem.. you have a product of 3 sequences of  functions each of them converges point wise to another function..so by product rule of limits the product of sequences of function converges to the product of the limit functions of each sequence.

Comment: Would this work if we change the $n$ in the exponent to $-n$ since the values for the integrand where $x \in [0,n]$ grow without bounds as $x \to n$?

Comment: I do not understand the last part as x-->n

Answer (score 2):

Here is another line of argument: Using the substitution $y = \frac{x}{n}$, the integral inside the limit reduces to

$$ \int_{0}^{1} n (1 - y) ^n \log(2+\cos y) \, \mathrm{d}y. $$

Now the following theorem kicks in:

> **Theorem.** Let $\phi : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be bounded and continuous at $0$. Then
>   $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1} n (1-y)^{n-1} \phi(y) \, \mathrm{d}y = \phi(0). $$

In our case, we can set $\phi(y) = (1-y) \log(2 + \cos y)$ to find out that the limit is $\phi(0) = \log 3$.

*Proof of Theorem.* For any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta \in (0, 1)$ such that $|\phi(y) - \phi(0)| < \epsilon$ whenever $|y| < \delta$. Also, let $M > 0$ be a bound of $\phi$. Then

\begin{align*}
\left| \int_{0}^{1} n (1-y)^{n-1} \phi(y) \, \mathrm{d}y - \phi(0) \right|
&\leq \int_{0}^{1} n (1-y)^{n-1} |\phi(y) - \phi(0)| \, \mathrm{d}y \\
&\leq 2M \int_{\delta}^{1} n (1-y)^{n-1} \, \mathrm{d}y + \epsilon \int_{0}^{\delta} n (1-y)^{n-1} \, \mathrm{d}y \\
&\leq 2M(1-\delta)^n + \epsilon,
\end{align*}

and so,

$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \left| \int_{0}^{1} n (1-y)^{n-1} \phi(y) \, \mathrm{d}y - \phi(0) \right| \leq \epsilon. $$

But since the left-hand side is independent of $\epsilon > 0$, we can let $\epsilon \downarrow 0$ to find that this limsup is zero, which implies the desired claim. $\square$